# PHP session variables not saving between pages

Tags: php, session-variables

I know this might be a duplicate question, but I can't seem to find an answer to my specific problem.

I have 3 PHP files. signin.php gets users data and passes it to signin_auth.php.

signin.php then redirects to mytoolkit.php after successful sign in.

signin_auth.php uses the following code at the very end of the PHP script:

```
<?
session_start();

$_SESSION['sessionID'] = $id;
$_SESSION['time'] = time();

header ("Location: mytoolkit.php");
exit;

?>
```

Then, the users is redirected to mytoolkit.php, which uses this code:

```
<?

session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['sessionID'])) {

    header('Location: signin.php?message=4');
        exit;

}

$inactive = 5400;
$session_life = time() - $_SESSION['time'];

if ($session_life > $inactive) { 

   session_destroy(); 
   header("Location: signin.php?message=5"); 
   exit;

}

?>
```

The session variables aren't storing and mytoolkit.php keeps redirecting me to signin.php?message=4

Probably a stupid mistake. I've just been looking at it too long.

UPDATE --

So I have a couple of servers. Both on iPage. I moved the entire folder over to a differnent server (abc.com/toolkit is now copied to xyz.com/toolkit) The app runs perfectly on xyz.com... it the first server that's giving me probelms.

There both run on the same hosting company. I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: why are you using session_life and inactive to destroy the session, and you're not letting php kill it by itself when it is inactive for X time that you can set in php.ini ??

Comment: You say at the very end of sign auth there is that session code, are you outputting html or even a blank line somewhere before?

Comment: @on_, i was going to ask the same thing; code to the very end of page and `session_start()` cant go together, along with whitespaces prev to it.

Comment: white spaces inside php isn't an issue with session_start, as long as the white spaces aren't actual outputs it isn't an issue.

Comment: @on_, I'm not outputting any html - signing_auth.php is strictly php.

Comment: Once I had issues like this because global variables were on on a hostgator server...

Comment: Tip: `session_destroy();` is not a good idea, unless you are sure what you are doing. Prefer to use something like `$_SESSION['xxxxx'] = null;` or `unset($_SESSION['xxxxx']);`

Answer (score 4):

I finally figured it out... It was an issues with my `php.ini` file on iPage's server. For some reason, they had it set to

```
session.save_path = "/var/php_sessions"
```

Where it should be my document root. That's not the first time they've messed stuff up.

Comment: if I read this [php docs page](http://www.php.net/session.configuration) correctly, `session.save_path` should be defaulted to `""`

Comment: on my local computer (php 5.3), `session.save_path = "C:\SERVER\tmp"`, but on my webhost it was the same as Sean's: `session.save_path = "/var/php_sessions"` ... ... changing it to `""` worked.

Comment: THIS IS MISINFORMATION! You do NOT want to store your sessions in your document root. It will expose everyone's sessions publicly unless the file permissions are right.

Answer (score 1):

if you did not destroy session with `session_destroy();` before `if (!isset($_SESSION['sessionID'])) {` statement, then a reason could be `$id` has null value.

Comment: `session_destroy();` is not a good idea, unless you are sure what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your issue

```
  $inactive = 5400;
  $session_life = time() - $_SESSION['time'];
  if ($session_life > $inactive) { 
       session_destroy(); 
       header("Location: signin.php?message=5"); 
       exit;
  }
```

Comment: I took it out completely, still failed. Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `header('location: example.com')` in your script it is sending a 302 redirect to your browser. Now this is none permanent, but some browser still cache this result. Just [google it](http://www.google.nl/search?hl=nl&q=php%20header%20location%20cached#hl=nl&sclient=psy-ab&q=302%20redirect%20cached&oq=302%20redirect%20cached&gs_l=serp.3..0i10.55436.55436.1.55668.1.1.0.0.0.0.59.59.1.1.0...0.0...1c.1.12.psy-ab.51tM_D7keiE&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&fp=994da1c58fca6af5&biw=1280&bih=929)

So it could very well be that your browser is redirecting your request before it even accesses your code. Try changing `signin_auth.php` to `header ("Location: mytoolkit.php?t=".time());` and then call the page with some random parameter attached to prevent the first page from caching. EG: `/signin_auth.php?t=random`

Answer (score 0):

I was running httpd as another user (not apache). On checking /etc/php.ini I found that "session directory must be owned by process owner". So in /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf I changed the following:

```
php_value session.save_path    "/var/lib/php/session"
php_value soap.wsdl_cache_dir  "/var/lib/php/wsdlcache"
```

to

```
php_value session.save_path    "/home/[httpduser]/php/session"
php_value soap.wsdl_cache_dir  "/home/[httpduser]/php/wsdlcache"
```

and reloaded httpd.

Not sure if it was a better idea to change the owner of /var/lib/php to [httpduser]